# Rails Axlsx Gem: How to switch between worksheets within a workbook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, excel, axlsx

I am writing to a workbook where each iteration over an array, I add new worksheet to the workbook.

```
 a = [1,2,3,4]
    p = Axlsx::Package.new
    a.each do |arr|        
        p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Name Sheet_#{arr}") do |sheet|
         sheet.add_row(["#","Name", "Status"]
         sheet.add_row(["1","ABC", 1]
         sheet.add_row(["2","XYZ", 0]
        end
        p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Address Sheet_#{arr}") do |sheet|
         sheet.add_row(["#","Address", "Status"]
         sheet.add_row(["1","NYC", 0]
         sheet.add_row(["2","LA", 1]
        end
#add a summary worksheet

    end
```

Now I want to add a summary sheet which will have records of Status 1 from all the worksheets. The summary sheet will be added only once (Axlsx will throw a duplicate sheet error anyway)

1: Can Axlsx open a worksheet in a workbook and append rows to it?
2: Is there any way for me to check if in a workbook , particular worksheet exists? (search by worksheet name)

Answer (score 1):

You can open an existing worksheet by selecting it by the worksheet name (which has to be unique).

**1. Can Axlsx open a worksheet in a workbook and append rows to it?**

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new

# Create the worksheet
p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Name Sheet_1") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["#","Name", "Status"]
    sheet.add_row ["1","ABC", 1]
    sheet.add_row ["2","XYZ", 0]
end

# Select the worksheet
sheet = p.workbook.worksheets.select {|w| w.name == "Name Sheet_1"}.first
sheet.add_row [1, 2, 3]
```

**2. Is there any way for me to check if in a workbook, particular worksheet exists? (search by worksheet name)**

```
p = Axlsx::Package.new 

# Create the worksheet
p.workbook.add_worksheet(:name => "Name Sheet_1") do |sheet|
    sheet.add_row ["#","Name", "Status"]
    sheet.add_row ["1","ABC", 1]
    sheet.add_row ["2","XYZ", 0]
end

# Search for the worksheet by name   
p.workbook.worksheets.any? {|worksheet| worksheet.name == "Name Sheet_1"} # true
p.workbook.worksheets.any? {|worksheet| worksheet.name == "Name Sheet_2"} # false
```